# open web page onclick

Tags: java, android

How can I create a web page on the back of a touch button while working in Android Studio?

I believe it is possible through the URI.

Comment: You need to ask question to the point to your problem in English statements that other can understand. 
Otherwise you will not get effective answers to your problem as they will be only assumptions.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://stackoverflow.com"));
startActivity(browserIntent);
```